# Lava Scatter chart unable to display year

Tags: laravel, charts

I m trying to add year wise records here

```html
$defect_reported_by_year = Lava::DataTable();

     $defect_reported_by_year->addDateColumn("Year")
     ->addNumberColumn('Value')
     ->setDateTimeFormat('Y')
  ->addRow(['2011', 20])
  ->addRow(['2012', 100])
  ->addRow(['2013', 22])
  ->addRow(['2014', 34])
  ->addRow(['2015', 65]);

  Lava::ScatterChart('defect_reported_by_year', $defect_reported_by_year, [
      'width' => 1000,
      'height' => 500,
      'title' => 'Defects Reported by Year',
      'legend' => [
          'position' => 'none'
      ]
  ]);
```

but output shows slipt of 6 months. This how currently its showing up, can anyone help me to display only 2011, 2012 and so on[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just passed the [DateRange](http://lavacharts.com/#dashboards-filters) to avoid the range.

```
$defect_reported_by_year = Lava::DataTable();

$defect_reported_by_year->addDateColumn("Year")
->addNumberColumn('Value')
->setDateTimeFormat('Y')
->addRow(['2011', 20])
->addRow(['2012', 100])
->addRow(['2013', 22])
->addRow(['2014', 34])
->addRow(['2015', 65]);

//Apply DateRange filter
$defect_reported_by_year->DateRangeFilter('Year', 1, 1, 'Y');

Lava::ScatterChart('defect_reported_by_year', $defect_reported_by_year, [
    'width' => 1000,
    'height' => 500,
    'title' => 'Defects Reported by Year',
    'legend' => [
        'position' => 'none'
    ]
]);
```

Not tested this thing, may this will help you.